# error CC1071: Arguments to contract validator call are too complicated. Please simplify

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, code-contracts

Any ideas what does it mean?
The call looks like:

```
Require.IsTrue(value == null || type.IsInstanceOfType(value),
    "value",
    "The specified value must be an instance of the specified type.");
```

**UPD:**

```
[ContractArgumentValidator]
public static void IsTrue(
    Boolean condition, String paramName, String message)
{
    if(!condition)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(message, paramName);
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
}
```

Comment: Value must be null or type must be an object of the type that's supposed to be specified by value.

Comment: @MihaiTodor, this is what the code is doing. The question is why does it complain about it being too complicated condition.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/b2a2d7e4-7eb2-411f-b74f-e2b413c60d9b (I'm not familiar with the ContractArgumentValidator)

Comment: Why not just `Contract.Requires`?

Comment: @Porges, because the Require.IsTrue is an existing method used throughout the code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a || or && operator in the argument to a validator. The decompilation does not support it.